# Ping command with parameters from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ping

How I can execute ping command with parameter -s (size of package) from iPhone device. I need it for access to my router with help of knocking mechanism.

I tried different apps in AppStore - no success.
Apps List:

[Ping - network utility](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ping-network-utility/id576773404?mt=8)

[Termius - SSH client](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/termius-ssh-client/id549039908)

Maybe, someone know appropriate one?

Comment: Can you add the names of the apps you have tried, to prevent answers which recommend the same apps again.

Comment: Yes, it is not problem. I will add them to the main post.

Answer (score 1):

[IT Tools - Network Analyzer](https://itunes.apple.com/app/it-tools-network-analyzer/id324054954) iOS app has a configuration screen for ping, which includes Payload Size:

[image]

Comment: Thank you.
Maybe, existing apps with no payment for installing?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know - I haven't tried many - that's the app I have.

Comment: For this case, I use Termius on my Andorid device and it is free.
Termius for iPhone haven't feature which i need. It's pity.